# How to get all selected TableCell from a Table in WPF RichTextBox? I tried to get all TableCell by using TextSelection but this gives wrong results

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, richtextbox, rtf, flowdocument

I am new to Windows Presentation Framework, don't know most of it. Please answer with example code, how to get only all selected `TableCell` from a Table in WPF `RichTextBox`? I tried to get all the selected `TableCell` items by using `TextSelection`.Start and `TextSelection`.End but this gives wrong results. This yields selected cells but also one or more unselected unwanted cells. It seems a bug in WPF `Richtextbox`, or my code implementation is wrong and some other code is to be implemented. No idea what the code is to get only the selected `TableCel`l items without any additional unselected `TableCell`. Kindly also inform example code to get all selected `TableRow` of a Table.

```cs
public List<TableCell> GetSelectedCells(System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox rtb, TextSelection selection)
{
    List<TableCell> cells = new List<TableCell>();
    var curCaret = CaretPosition;
    Table table = rtb.Document.Blocks.OfType<Table>().Where(x => x.ContentStart.CompareTo(curCaret) == -1 && x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(curCaret) == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (table == null) return cells;
    if (table.RowGroups.Count == 0) return cells;

    foreach (TableRowGroup rowGroup in table.RowGroups)
    {
        foreach (TableRow row in rowGroup.Rows)
        {
            // option 1, this also yields additional unselected cells
            List<TableCell> selcells = row.Cells.Where(w => selection.Contains(w.ContentStart) && selection.Contains(w.ContentEnd)).ToList();

            // option 2, this also yields additional unselected cells.
            foreach (TableCell cell in selcells)
            {
                if (selection.Contains(cell.ElementStart) && selection.Contains(cell.ElementEnd))
                    cells.Add(cell);
            }
        }
    }
    return cells;
}
```

I tried 2 different code which is described as "option 1" or "option 2" or both options. i cannot get perfect and exact results but only wrong results with additional unselected unwanted `TableCell`. I want to get all the selected `TableCell` items only, but not any other `TableCell`.

Comment: The Table is meant to be a pure layout element. If you need user interaction better use the DataGrid. Just use a BlockUIContainer or InlineUIContainer to host it. DataGrid extends MultiSelector and therefore provides a selected row/cell handling API.

Comment: my primary objective is loading .rtf and saving .rtf files. DataGrid is a Control. Table renders perfectly into an .rtf file. Will integrating DataGrid into Document render perfectly into .rtf file?

Comment: No, WPF can't convert every UIElements to RTF compliant code. The element must be supported by the WPF FlowDocument engine. But you can manually convert a DataGrid to a Table and vice versa.

Comment: Only elements that are part of the content model are supported by the API.

Comment: I am developing a free open source journaling software. So .rtf file load and save are mandatory in a journaling software. Table editing in one of the most important parts in a journaling software. I need to select multiple TableCell in a TableRow and must get all the selected TableCell only. I am absolutely new to WPF and using it in WinForms. I will try DataGrid as the last resort if Table cannot be used.

Comment: Selecting one or more TableCell are actually giving results as I described. Most of the selected TableCell are correctly selected. But the results are still wrong, one additional unselected TableCell is also being produced at the tail of the selection through Selection.Start and Selection.End. My code may be wrong or incomplete. Hope I solve this problem soon.

Comment: yes off course as I don't know what the correct implementation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlowDocument` is a component based document model.
This means, it is generally a bad idea to search the document text based when you are interested in elements of the content model, for example a `TableCell`.

The general approach is to use a `TextPointer` context based search as this is the only convenient way to get access to the content elements.

The idea is to get the `TextPointer` that points to the start of an element. Then check if this element is the element of interest. If it's not, advance the `TextPointer` to the next position by using the `TextPointer` API.

To support your open source project I will post a modified example of some library code. It's reduced to satisfy the minimum requirement without sacrificing the generic nature. I have also annotated it with some comments that help to understand the implementation. For convenience, I have converted the code into an extension method.

The following algorithm is a generic implementation that allows to find any kind of `ContentElement` or `UIElement`.

As a general note, the implementation of `TryGetNextElement` shows the common algorithm to step through a `FlowDocument` context based to inspect its elements:

**TextRangeHelper.cs**

```cs
public static class TextRangeHelper
{
  public static IEnumerable<TElement> EnumerateElements<TElement>(this TextRange documentRange)
      where TElement : DependencyObject
  {
    if (!TryGetFirstElementStartPositionInContentRange<TElement>(documentRange, out TextPointer selectedElementStart))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    TextPointer contentPosition = selectedElementStart;
    while (TryGetNextElement(ref contentPosition, documentRange.End, out TElement contentElement))
    {
      yield return contentElement;
      contentPosition = contentPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }

    yield break;
  }

  // In case the TextRange e.g. content selection starts inside the requested element,
  // we need to adjust the text range to include the current element.
  private static bool TryGetFirstElementStartPositionInContentRange<TElement>(TextRange documentRange, out TextPointer selectedElementStart)
    where TElement : DependencyObject
  {
    selectedElementStart = documentRange.Start;
    DependencyObject? contentElement = selectedElementStart?.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (contentElement is TElement)
    {
      return true;
    }

    // Step backward to capture the first TableCell element in the current selection
    while (selectedElementStart is not null)
    {
      TextPointerContext textPointerContext = selectedElementStart!.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);

      // Filter pointer context of content elements (TextPointerContext.ElementStart)
      // and UIElements contained in a BlockUIContainer or InlineUIContainer (TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement)
      if (textPointerContext is not (TextPointerContext.ElementStart or TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement))
      {
        selectedElementStart = selectedElementStart!.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
        continue;
      }

      contentElement = selectedElementStart!.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);

      // Selection starts inside or after the potential target element.
      // This means we must return the coerced start pointer to make the selection start ahead of the original.
      if (contentElement is TElement)
      {
        return true;
      }

      // Selection starts before the potential target element.
      // This means we can return the original selection start pointer.
      else if (contentElement is not (Block or Inline)
        || (contentElement is FrameworkContentElement frameworkContentElement && frameworkContentElement.Parent is FlowDocument))
      {
        selectedElementStart = documentRange.Start;
        return true;
      }

      selectedElementStart = selectedElementStart!.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    }

    return false;
  }

  private static bool TryGetNextElement<TElement>(ref TextPointer contentPosition, TextPointer contentEndPosition, out TElement nextElement)
    where TElement : DependencyObject
  {
    nextElement = default;

    if (IsEndOfContent(contentPosition, contentEndPosition))
    {
      return false;
    }

    nextElement = contentPosition?.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward) as TElement;
    if (nextElement is not null)
    {
      return true;
    }

    // Step forward to find and collect next TableCell in current selection
    while (contentPosition is not null
      && !IsEndOfContent(contentPosition, contentEndPosition))
    {
      TextPointerContext contentPositionContext = contentPosition!.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);

      // Filter pointer context of content elements (TextPointerContext.ElementStart)
      // and UIElements contained in a BlockUIContainer or InlineUIContainer (TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement)
      if (contentPositionContext is not (TextPointerContext.ElementStart or TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement))
      {
        contentPosition = contentPosition!.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        continue;
      }

      nextElement = contentPosition!.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward) as TElement;
      if (nextElement is not null)
      {
        return true;
      }

      contentPosition = contentPosition!.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }

    return false;
  }

  private static bool IsEndOfContent(TextPointer contentPosition, TextPointer contentEndPosition)
  {
    if (contentPosition is null || contentEndPosition is null)
    {
      return true;
    }

    // If the pointer is pointing to the next insertion point (LogicalDirection.Forward),
    // we must reverse the end pointer to exclude the next trailing content.
    if (contentEndPosition.LogicalDirection == LogicalDirection.Forward)
    {
      contentEndPosition = contentEndPosition?.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    }

    return contentPosition?.CompareTo(contentEndPosition) >= 0;
  }
}
```

### Usage Example

After selecting some text in the `Table` within a `FlowDocument`, a `Button.Click` handler will actually execute the extraction of the selected `TableCell` items and their cell values:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  IEnumerable<TableCell> cells = this.RichTextBox.Selection.EnumerateElements<TableCell>();
  IEnumerable<string> cellValues = cells.Select(cell => new TextRange(cell.ContentStart, cell.ContentEnd).Text);
}
```